# Use Async/Await with Axios in React.js

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, asynchronous, ecmascript-2017

Following

**[How to use async/await with axios in react](https://medium.com/@adityasingh_32512/how-to-use-async-await-with-axios-in-react-e07daac2905f)**

I am trying to make a simple get request to my server using Async/Await in a React.js App. 
The server loads a simple JSON at `/data` which looks like this

**JSON**

```
{
   id: 1,
   name: "Aditya"
}
```

I am able to get the data to my React App using simple jquery ajax get method.
However, I want to make use of axios library and Async/Await to follow ES7 standards.
My current code looks like this:

```
class App extends React.Component{
 async getData(){
     const res = await axios('/data');
     console.log(res.json());
 }
 render(){
     return(
         <div>
             {this.getData()}
         </div>
     );
 }
}
```

Using this approach I get the following error:

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If
>   you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Am I not implementing it correctly?

Comment: render() is working just fine as I clearly mentioned that I am able to get details when I use $.ajax(). What extra code should I add? This is a simple get request to the server using ES7 standards.

Comment: Ideally, update your question with a **runnable** [mcve] demonstrating the problem using a placeholder for the ajax (e.g., `setTimeout` or similar), using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: ...but the added code absolutely makes things clear. :-)

Comment: FYI, `async/await` is part of ES2017, **not** ES7 (ES2016).

Comment: Thank you for the information.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Two issues jump out:

1. Your `getData` never returns anything, so its promise (`async` functions always return a promise) will be fulfilled with `undefined` if it doesn't reject
2. The error message clearly shows you're trying to directly render the promise `getData` returns, rather than waiting for it to settle and then rendering the fulfillment value

Addressing #1: `getData` should *return* the result of calling `json`:

```
async getData(){
   const res = await axios('/data');
   return await res.json();
}
```

Addressig #2: We'd have to see more of your code, but fundamentally, you can't do

```
<SomeElement>{getData()}</SomeElement>
```

...because that doesn't wait for the resolution. You'd need instead to use `getData` to set state:

```
this.getData().then(data => this.setState({data}))
              .catch(err => { /*...handle the error...*/});
```

...and use that state when rendering:

```
<SomeElement>{this.state.data}</SomeElement>
```

---

**Update**: Now that you've shown us your code, you'd need to do *something like* this:

```
class App extends React.Component{
    async getData() {
        const res = await axios('/data');
        return await res.json(); // (Or whatever)
    }
    constructor(...args) {
        super(...args);
        this.state = {data: null};
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        if (!this.state.data) {
            this.getData().then(data => this.setState({data}))
                          .catch(err => { /*...handle the error...*/});
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.data ? <em>Loading...</em> : this.state.data}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**Futher update:** You've indicated a preference for using `await` in `componentDidMount` rather than `then` and `catch`. You'd do that by nesting an `async` IIFE function within it and ensuring that function can't throw. (`componentDidMount` itself can't be `async`, nothing will consume that promise.) E.g.:

```
class App extends React.Component{
    async getData() {
        const res = await axios('/data');
        return await res.json(); // (Or whatever)
    }
    constructor(...args) {
        super(...args);
        this.state = {data: null};
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        if (!this.state.data) {
            (async () => {
                try {
                    this.setState({data: await this.getData()});
                } catch (e) {
                    //...handle the error...
                }
            })();
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.data ? <em>Loading...</em> : this.state.data}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: It gave me this error "'this' is not allowed before super()". So I added super(); right before "this.state = {data: null};" which later resulted in a new error: "'getData' is not defined  no-undef"

Comment: @Morfsys: I don't think that's the exact error message. :-) I did say "*something like* this". I've updated the above, was missing `this.` on `getData`.

Comment: .catch(err => { /*...handle the error...*/}); executes now.It says res.json() is not a function.

Comment: @Morfsys: Well, then `res` doesn't have a `json` property that's a function. I just copied that from your code, I have no idea what `res` is or whether you should expect it to have a `json` function. (The result from `fetch` would, but I don't use axios.) That has nothing to do with the fundamentals described above, which are the primary thing you need to fix (though of course, you need to fix the `json` thing as well).

Comment: Just FYI... `return res.json()` would need to be `return await res.json()` in the example above, correct? If you are returning it on the next line, the return line will execute right away instead of waiting to be defined by `const res` right above it.

Comment: @dave4jr: No, you don't have to -- but it may be a good idea from a code maintenance standpoint, thanks. *"If you are returning it on the next line, the return line will execute right away instead of waiting..."* No, that's incorrect. The `return` line won't execute until the `await axios('/data')` resolves. So the code without the `await` would work, the promise created by `getData` being `async` would just slave to the one returned by `res.json()`. But from a code maint. pers., you're right, better to `await` it -- because it would be easy to mess it up when making changes to `getData`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Ahh yes you are correct, thanks for the explanation sir.

Comment: NOTE: In case of error --- e.response.data --- will have the actual error.

Answer (score 20):

In my experience over the past few months, I've realized that the best way to achieve this is:

```
class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(){
   super();
   this.state = {
    serverResponse: ''
   }
  }
  componentDidMount(){
     this.getData();
  }
  async getData(){
   const res = await axios.get('url-to-get-the-data');
   const { data } = await res;
   this.setState({serverResponse: data})
 }
 render(){
  return(
     <div>
       {this.state.serverResponse}
     </div>
  );
 }
}
```

If you are trying to make post request on events such as click, then call `getData()` function on the event and replace the content of it like so:

```
async getData(username, password){
 const res = await axios.post('url-to-post-the-data', {
   username,
   password
 });
 ...
}
```

Furthermore, if you are making any request when the component is about to load then simply replace `async getData()` with `async componentDidMount()` and change the render function like so:

```
render(){
 return (
  <div>{this.state.serverResponse}</div>
 )
}
```

Comment: This is basically just my answer, reworded. Also: 1. Don't make `componentWillMount` an `async` function. React will ignore the returned promise. 2. Unless `res.data` is an accessor returning a promise, it doesn't make any sense to use `await` when accessing it.

Comment: I've merely tried to simplify the answer. No offense, but I think `then` and `catch` is not the latest standard (ES6) of following up with a promise. In addition, res.json() wasn't working for me and so I had to replace it with res.data that comes along with a promise in`GET` or `POST` request.

Comment: `then` and `catch` **are** the ES2015 (aka "ES6") way to deal with promises. `async`/`await` are the ES2017 ("ES8") way. But you can only use `await` within an `async` function, and making `componentWillMount` `async` is creating a promise that will never be consumed. If you want to use `await` instead, that's fine, but you'd do that differently from just slapping `async` on `componentWillMount`. In any case, frankly, coming back two months later and posting an answer that just tweaks the existing one without atttribution isn't cool.

Answer (score 0):

```js
 async fetchCatFacts() {
    await axios.get("//localhost:8082/api_v1/orders", {})
        .then((response) => {

          this.catFacts = response.data.data;
          console.log("resp", response.data);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 const datasend = async () => {
    await axios.post(
      "http://localhost:5000/",
      {
        name: named,
        age: aged,
      },
      (response) => {
        console.log(response);
      }
    );
    console.log("data send");
  };
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).