# Using a function to get API data and populate a provider

Tags: reactjs, function, fetch

I try to fetch data from API using a function and then setState in my React provider.

It works fine if I'm doing it in `componentDidMount` directly like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
axios({
  method: "post",
  url: "https://example.com",
  // data: formData,
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
  }
}).then(res => {
  this.setState({
    TabPass: res.data
  });
});
    }
```

I tried to get to the same result but with axios put in function in a separate file  and once I get the data, I perform a setState in my provider.

I've tried this in api.js

```
export function GetPass ()
{
    axios({
        method: "post",
        url: https://example.com",
        // data: formData,
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
        }
      })
        .then(res => {
            return res.data;
        }
        )
}
```

In Provider.js

```
  componentDidMount() {

    const Tab = GetPass();
      this.setState({
        TabPass:Tab,
      })
    }
  }
```

Tab is undefined

Comment: Please post the code that isn't working for you so we can point out what needs to be fixed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use Async/Await with Axios in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46733354/use-async-await-with-axios-in-react-js)

Comment: This is because you're not waiting for the call to complete, your axios request is asynchronous

Comment: I'm aware of that what I' don't know is how to wait for the call to be complete using a separate function when I use setState

Comment: Tab is still undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In api.js

```
export function GetPass ()
{
    //Following will return a promise with the data once resolved
    return axios({
        method: "post",
        url: https://example.com",
        // data: formData,
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
        }
      })
        .then(res => {
            return res.data;
        }
        )
}
```

In Provider.js

```
componentDidMount() {
    // As the axios promise will resolved your state will change
    GetPass()
      .then(Tab => { this.setState({
        TabPass: Tab,
      }))
    }}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In the provider Tab is now a promise but I don't have the result (sorry I'm not an expert with react :) )

Comment: Try following ``` const Tab = GetPass().then(data => ```

Comment: I'd like to mark answer as correct but as I told you in my previous comment my const is not the result but a promise (with PromiseStatus and PromiseValue). How can I access the result ?

Comment: I have updated above answer. Check and revert if still got issue :)

Comment: Exactly what I neeeded. Thanks a lot