# How to call an Async function in Non-Async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, async-await, fetch

I am new to React Js, and trying to make an API call using `fetch`.

I have written a generic async function that I am using to API calls, to send requests to the API Endpoint. That function is being called in another class's function, that should parse the result and return the value to the parent function calling.

Here is my utility class with a function that calls the endpoint:

```
export default class RestUtil {
  getModel = async (model) => {
    let url = 'http://api.xyz.com/' + model;
    const apiCall = await fetch(url,
        {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer xyz'
            }
        });
    return  apiCall.json();
 }
}
```

Below is my React Component that is causing issues:

```
export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {
   componentDidMount() {
     this.populateUsersDropDown();
   }

   populateUsersDropDown() {
     let users = this.fetchUsers();
     // Here the `users` is undefined. <-------- Issue

     //Do some other work with users

     /*Populate users in 
                 the dropdown*/
   }

   fetchUsers() {
     new RestUtil()
         .getModel('users')
         .then(data => {
             /* Do some other work with data */
             return data;
         })
   }

}
```

Now I want the populateUsersDropDown() to wait for the fetchUsers() to complete it's `then` part and return the data and proceed. But I am receiving `undefined` in users variable. Wheres, in my `then` section, I am able to see the data.

Need some help in solving this please?

Comment: use async await in populateUsersDropDown

Comment: you can take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/58815843/5124488 ? I recommend using Axios

Comment: You should use a state variable and update it when API returns data. This will simplify things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `fetchUsers` method does not return anything.

```
    async fetchUsers() {
     const users = await new RestUtil().getModel('users');

     return users;
   }
```

This should work