# How React js & LocalStorage with Axios API response?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on react app,
Where generally user login and submit the form  and in form ,there are mulitple fields, which is select i.e drop-down fields  ,

whenever user logged in the system,

```
login = async (data = {}) => {
    try {
      // const { token, user } = await login(data);

      const { access_token, expires_at } = await login(data);
      const token = access_token;
      localStorage.setItem("token", token);
      const authToken = localStorage.getItem("token");

      const config = await getConfig(authToken);
      localStorage.setItem("config", JSON.stringify(config));

      initAxios();

      this.setState(
        {
          token,
        },
        () => {
          notify({
            type: "success",
            text: "Successfully logged in!",
          });
        }
      );
    } catch (error) {
      if (error.response.status === 401) {
        throw error;
      }
      notify({
        type: "error",
        text: getErrorMessage(error),
      });
    }
  };
```

I want to use this in my multiple form component where I can get this object,

What will be the best solution to retrieve the data from local storage ?

```
const configData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("config"));
export const category = configData.category;
export const gender = configData.gender;
......
```

& import in From Component and use it ,

Can it is possible to use it in directly form component with the help of useEffect() hooks?

Adding Code Snippet @Arnab, here

````js
if (localStorage.getItem("apiData")) { 
accessoriesConfig = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("apiData")); return accessoriesConfig; }
else{ 
return fetchOptions().then(response => localStorage.setItem("apiData", JSON.stringify(response)));
//this is returns me always promise as pending status ,that breaks my functionality 

} 
//API Call with axios
export async function fetchOptions() {
return getAxios("get","/api/config/") .then(response => response.data); 
} ```
````

Comment: I didn't understand your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting json response from your api, then you can save the data in Localstorage by selector which will be easier for you to retrieve later.

```
axios({
    url: 'APIplaceholder'
    adapter: jsonpAdapter
  }).then((res) => {     
        localStorage["name"]=res.data.name
        localStorage["email"]=res.data.email
  });
```

In That case, when you will try to retrieve, you can just call localstorage.get() function by key like this::

```
localStorage.getItem("name")
```

**Or else you can save the whole response as a string to localstorage like:**

```
axios({
        url: 'APIplaceholder'
        adapter: jsonpAdapter
      })
.then((res) => {
     localStorage.setItem("apiData", JSON.stringify(res.data));
});
```

and retrieve like this:

```
var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("apiData"));
```

Then access them with dot(.) operator as an object. `data.name`

Comment: PLeasure is mine. Hope the answer was helpful

Comment: Hi @Arnab ,
I am trying to save the api response on login of user ,
but I want to try below ,


``` lang-js

if (localStorage.getItem("apiData")) {
    accessoriesConfig = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("apiData"));
    return accessoriesConfig;
    }else{
     return fetchOptions().then(response => localStorage.setItem("apiData", JSON.stringify(response)));

this is returns me always promise as pending status ,that breaks my functionality
    } 
export async function fetchOptions() {
  return getAxios("get","/api/config/")
    .then(response => response.data);
}
```

Comment: Can you share it as an answer or a different snippet  with formatted? its difficult to understand now

Comment: Yeah ,I modified the post and added the code at bottom,In Comment section I cant highlight the code @Arnab

Comment: `getAxios("get","/api/config/") .then(response => response.data);`  here after getting response from the API, you need to store it to localstorage

Comment: `const configData = getAxios("get","/api/config/").then(    response => {      localStorage.setItem("config", JSON.stringify(response.data))      return response.data;}   );`
`console.log(configData);`
`// THIS Will return me promise with pending status`
`export const salutation = configData.salutation;`

Comment: I can successfully set the values in local storage but,cant get  the  values from function,as its is returning me promise with pending state.

Comment: Can you share your `response.data` please?

Comment: {
 "accessories_city": {
  "ADILABAD": "ADILABAD",
  "AGRA": "AGRA",
  "MUMBAI":"MUMBAI"
 },
 "salutation": {
  "MR": "Mr.",
  "MRS": "Mrs.",
  "MS": "Miss",
  "DR": "Dr."
 }
}
```


This is the response

Comment: Its because your function is returning value before getting data from axios. Make the function async like and then call axios as await.
 `const res = await axios('/data');`   and  ` return await res.json();`

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46733354/use-async-await-with-axios-in-react-js

Answer (score 0):

Solution I applied here is below,

```
export async function fetchOptions() {
    var configData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("config"));
    if(configData){
      return configData;
    }else{
    return getAxios("get","/api/config/")
      .then(response => {      
        localStorage.setItem('config',JSON.stringify(response.data));
        return response.data;
      });
    }
  }


Importing in Components and Files.

import {fetchOptions} from '../../requests';
var configData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("config"));
if(!configData) {
  fetchOptions().then(res => {
    setConfigValue(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("config")));
  });
}else{
  setConfigValue(configData);
}
```