# Unable to set state from the response of the api

Tags: react-native

I have a following function in Api.js

```
const _getCategories = async () => {
  var categories = [];
  let token = await getJwt();
  var config = {
    method: 'get',
    url: 'myurl',
    headers: { 
      'Authorization': 'Bearer' + ' ' + token
    },
    data : ''
  };
  
  axios(config)
  .then(function (response) {
    if(response.status == 200)
    {
      let res = response.data;
     // Create a variable having name in the list.
       categories = res.data.apps.map(function(item) {
         return {
           title: item.name,
           color: AppStyles.colorSet.analyticsColor,
           lightColor: AppStyles.colorSet.analyticsLightColor,
           icon: AppStyles.iconSet.analytics
         };
       });
      // console.log('Returning Categories');
       console.log(categories);
       return categories;
       //console.log(data1)
      // Handle and fetch the list of apps
    }
    else 
    {
      // API didn't go through, generate the error functions 
    }
    
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
  
  
};
```

and I am loading it in homscreen.js

```
class DashboardScreen extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    

    const { navigation } = props;
    navigation.setOptions({
      title: 'Dashboard',
      headerLeft: () => (
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => {
            navigation.openDrawer();
          }}
        >
          <Icon
            style={AppStyles.styleSet.menuButton}
            name="ios-menu"
            size={AppStyles.iconSizeSet.normal}
            color={AppStyles.colorSet.mainThemeForegroundColor}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      ),
    });
    this.state = {
      categories: [],
    };
  }
componentDidMount() {
    if (!this.state.data) {
        Api.getCategories().then(data => console.log("The data is "+data))
                      .catch(err => { /*...handle the error...*/});
    } 
}

  onPressCategory = item => {
    // Handle onpress for the items
  };

  render() {
    //console.log(this.state.categories);
    categoryButtonsRow1 = this.state.categories.map((item, index) => {
      if (index < 3) {
        return (
          <CategoryButton
            onPress={() => this.onPressCategory(item)}
            color={item.color}
            lightColor={item.lightColor}
            icon={item.icon}
            title={item.title}
          />
        );
      }
    });
    return (
      <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.row}>{categoryButtonsRow1}</View>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}
```

But I am getting category as undefined while printing in render().

I even tried to create an async function in the homescreen.js and call the api with await and set the state after the same but still it is coming as undefined.

Any guesses to what I am doing wrong here. Can anyone help with the same. My best guess is that I am not handling the api request properly.

**EDIT**
I tried [Use Async/Await with Axios in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46733354/use-async-await-with-axios-in-react-js) but it is still printing undefined to the same.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use Async/Await with Axios in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46733354/use-async-await-with-axios-in-react-js)

Comment: @GuruparanGiritharan I tried this, but I still am getting undefined while setting the state. Here is the code that I tried. 

`componentDidMount() {
    if (!this.state.data) {
        Api.getCategories().then(data => console.log("The data is "+data))
                      .catch(err => { /*...handle the error...*/});
    } 
}`

Comment: The printed response above is coming to be undefined.

Comment: Did you try await axios.get(... ) ?

Comment: @GuruparanGiritharan I am using the same as shown in api.js as well.

Comment: the api method, try returning return axios(config); and try with the same code as your comment with  componentDidMount

Comment: @GuruparanGiritharan It returns me on the logs as " The data is [object Object] "

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224395/discussion-between-dper-and-guruparan-giritharan).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for getting undefined is the _getCategories is that its not returning anything and you are chaining using .then to get data so the caller has no way to get this data as a callback is not passed.

You can change the to await like this

```
const _getCategories = async () => {
  var categories = [];
  let token = await getJwt();
  var config = {
    method: 'get',
    url: 'myurl',
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer' + ' ' + token,
    },
    data: '',
  };

  const response = await axios(config);
  if (response.status == 200) {
    let res = response.data;
    // Create a variable having name in the list.
    categories = res.data.apps.map(function (item) {
      return {
        title: item.name,
        color: AppStyles.colorSet.analyticsColor,
        lightColor: AppStyles.colorSet.analyticsLightColor,
        icon: AppStyles.iconSet.analytics,
      };
    });
    // console.log('Returning Categories');
    console.log(categories);
    return categories;
    //console.log(data1)
    // Handle and fetch the list of apps
  } else {
    // API didn't go through, generate the error functions
    return null;
  }
};
```

And you can set the state in componentDidMount (should be async)

```
this.setState({categories:await api._getCategories()});
```