# Issue with Axios / React return undefined

Tags: reactjs, rest, axios, python-requests, get

I have an issue with React when I try to retrieve the value of return.

The code:

```
export const RuoloOnline = (jwt) => {
    axios.get("http://localhost:1337/api/users/me",
        {
            headers: {
                "Authorization": `Bearer ${jwt}`
            }
        }
    ).then((res) => { return (res.data.ruolo) }).catch(() => {return 0})
```

if I put a console.log the value is correctly viewed. If I try to call this function outside the file, it generates an undefined return.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use Async/Await with Axios in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46733354/use-async-await-with-axios-in-react-js)

Comment: Note that the browsers' console.log is lazily evaluated (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17546953/cant-access-object-property-even-though-it-exists-returns-undefined for more).

Answer (score 0):

Try using asynchronous function calls instead of this function. Your modified code will be

```
export const RuoloOnline = async (jwt) ={
    return await axios.get("http://localhost:1337/api/users/me",
       {
           headers: { 
                "Authorization": `Bearer ${jwt}`
            }
        }
   );
}
```

Hope it helps!